# Error: The method 'copyWith' isn't defined for the class 'RouteSettings'

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, thingsboard

I'm trying to run a sample of flutter , that thingsboard.io published in [this starting guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/mobile/getting-started/).
sample code : https://github.com/thingsboard/flutter_thingsboard_app

when i run start debuging in VS Code, i get this error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/fluro-2.0.3/lib/src/fluro_router.dart:134:37: Error: The method 'copyWith' isn't defined for the class 'RouteSettings'.
- 'RouteSettings' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/navigator.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'copyWith'.
      settingsToUse = settingsToUse.copyWith(name: path);
                                    ^^^^^^^^

Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1151

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

i'm newborn in mobile application, please help me, what should i do?

i want run this sample by VS code.

Comment: problem was for version of "fluro" in project, i update it, and problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run `flutter pub upgrade`. I
was facing the same problem and it worked

Answer (score 1):

`RouteSettings.copyWith` was removed.

Just use

From:

```
RouteSettings newSettings = oldSettings.copyWith(name: 'new name');
```

To:

```
RouteSettings newSettings = RouteSettings(name: 'new name', arguments: oldSettings.arguments);
```